# uwsgi 2.0.17 + django 2.0.3 worker crash sporadically

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am running uwsgi 2.0.17 in combination with a nginx infront and a Django 2.0.3 behind in a docker container. 1,6% of my request are failing due to uwsgi dying for some reasons. The logfileslook like this:

```
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 108) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 149)
```

It happens on random URI's, so no specific view causing it. My uwsgi.ini looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
# this config will be loaded if nothing specific is specified
# load base config from below
ini = :base

# %d is the dir this configuration file is in
socket = %dapp.sock
master = true
processes = 4

# pot. fix for prematurely closed upstream error
limit-as = 512

[dev]
ini = :base
# socket (uwsgi) is not the same as http, nor http-socket
socket = :8001

[local]
ini = :base
http = :8000

[base]
# chdir to the folder of this config file, plus app/website
chdir = %dserver
# load the module from wsgi.py, it is a python path from 
# the directory above.
module=server.wsgi:application
# allow anyone to connect to the socket. This is very permissive
chmod-socket=666
```

Any idea on how to trace the reason for dying or fixing the issue?